# UIViewcontentMode/Auto layout issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm displaying an array of images in a UIPageViewController. Everything works great in portrait mode (I have set the default auto layout constraints)

[image]

But when I turn the page in landscape mode my images sometimes end up like this.

[image]

But I'd like them to show in landscape mode like this - [image]

I have set the content modes like this

```
- (void) willTransitionToTraitCollection:(UITraitCollection *)newCollection withTransitionCoordinator:(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator>)coordinator{
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
else
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
}
```

And in my -viewWillAppear i set the same thing

```
    //when device is in landscape, center the image on the screen
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

//when user goes back to portrait mode, set back to normal
else
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;
```

But for some reason every once in a while the image will be stretched out in landscape mode.

Thanks for any help you can provide, and please let me know if theres anything else I can add.

Thank you so much

EDIT

when I set it to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;` always, the it ends up with bars below and above like this [image]

Comment: You shouldn't need to do anything with rotation at all. Just set it to `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` in all cases.

Comment: Surely though, when displaying text (like you are doing) then you don't want any stretching in any direction. Stretching text will just make it harder to read. `o` will look like `O`, `.` will look like `|` and so on. If there are diagrams in your images then circles will not be circles anymore.

Comment: I guess your right. Thanks